# assign global variable into index

Tags: php, global

i need to pass the title who i generate throw class code to the header file

this is my index:

```
 require('files/inc/config.php');
require('files/assets/php/header.php');
require('files/libs/Plantilla.class.php');
$plantilla = new plantilla($serv,$user,$pass,$base,$url,$sitio);
$pagina = empty($_GET['pagina']) ? "inicio" : $general->limpiar($_GET['pagina']);
    switch ($pagina) {
            case 'blog':
            $ids = $plantilla->docs($month,$view,$ref,$titles);
            $ref = $_GET['ref'];
            $month = $_GET['month'];
            $view = $_GET['view'];
            $titles = $_GET['titles'];
            echo $ids[0];  
            $tsTitle = $ids[1];
            break;
        default:
            echo $plantilla->docs($month,$view,$ref,$titles);
            $ref = $_GET['ref'];
            $month = $_GET['month'];
            $view = $_GET['view'];
            $titles = $_GET['titles'];
            break;
    }
require('files/assets/php/footer.php');
```

the variable $tsTitle is displayed in header.php and footer.php

```
<?php
    $titulo = $tsTitle;
    ?>
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <title><?php echo $titulo;?></title>
```

my problem is $tsTitle only displays on footer.php
how i can display in both files?

y assign a vale inside a case $tsTitle = $ids[1]; which is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your script a little bit.

```
require('files/inc/config.php');
require('files/libs/Plantilla.class.php');


$plantilla = new plantilla($serv,$user,$pass,$base,$url,$sitio);
$data_Holder = '';

$pagina = empty($_GET['pagina']) ? "inicio" : $general->limpiar($_GET['pagina']);
    switch ($pagina) {
            case 'blog':
            $ids = $plantilla->docs($month,$view,$ref,$titles);
            $ref = $_GET['ref'];
            $month = $_GET['month'];
            $view = $_GET['view'];
            $titles = $_GET['titles'];

            $data_Holder = $ids[0];  

            $tsTitle = $ids[1];
            break;
        default:
            $data_Holder = $plantilla->docs($month,$view,$ref,$titles);
            $ref = $_GET['ref'];
            $month = $_GET['month'];
            $view = $_GET['view'];
            $titles = $_GET['titles'];
            break;
    }

require('files/assets/php/header.php');
echo $data_Holder;
require('files/assets/php/footer.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your code position

```
require('files/inc/config.php');

require('files/libs/Plantilla.class.php');
$plantilla = new plantilla($serv,$user,$pass,$base,$url,$sitio);
$pagina = empty($_GET['pagina']) ? "inicio" : $general->limpiar($_GET['pagina']);
    switch ($pagina) {
            case 'blog':
            $ids = $plantilla->docs($month,$view,$ref,$titles);
            $ref = $_GET['ref'];
            $month = $_GET['month'];
            $view = $_GET['view'];
            $titles = $_GET['titles'];
            echo $ids[0];  
            $tsTitle = $ids[1];
            break;
        default:
            echo $plantilla->docs($month,$view,$ref,$titles);
            $ref = $_GET['ref'];
            $month = $_GET['month'];
            $view = $_GET['view'];
            $titles = $_GET['titles'];
            break;
    }
require('files/assets/php/header.php');
require('files/assets/php/footer.php');
```

Comment: i did it but this is the result http://prntscr.com/5ygip6 the code s called first and the the header

Comment: in this case the switch statement echo the value before header.